# Passing variable between pages and get result based on it in asp.net

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, session

Previous Page

```
test.Controls.Add(GetButton(thisReader["session_id"].ToString(), "Join Session"));


 protected void Button_Click(object sender, CommandEventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("EnterSession.aspx?session=" + e.CommandArgument.ToString());
        }
```

on the Next Page EnterSession.aspx

I want to use the `session_id` to return the result `session_name` from ms sql database based `session_id`.Then  I want to get the value of `session_name` which corresponds to the `session_id` and call the value using this JS method:

```
document.getElementById('session_name').value).
```

Some idea how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to achieve (e.g. what/where is the element with id 'session_name'?), but I think you need something like the following in the code behind of your  EnterSession.aspx page:

```
protected string _SessionName = null;
public string SessionName
{
    get
    {
        if (null == _SessionName)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection("connString"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                using (var command = new SqlCommand(" SELECT session_name FROM Sessions WHERE session_id = @SessionId", connection))
                {
                    command.Parameters.Add("@SessionId", SqlDbType.Int);
                    command.Parameters["@SessionId"].Value = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["session"]);

                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        if (reader.Read())
                        {
                            _SessionName = reader.GetString(0);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid session id");
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return _SessionName;
    }
    }
```

And then in the markup of the EnterSession.aspx page you would need something like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="session_name" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('session_name').value = '<%= this.SessionName %>';
</script>
```

Comment: thanx a lot . what is SqlDbType.Int

Comment: i get an error saying use AddWithValue(parameterName object value)

Comment: SqlDbType.Int refers to the SQL type of the value you are passing. I'm not sure why you would get that error as my code seems to work OK when I run it. You can ignore the parameters and just pass the session id as part of the SQL statement if you like.

Comment: Ian i added the code as i modified(from ur code) to pass my code. do u see any errors. under modification